# Httpclient.getasync() not working in windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-8, windows-8.1

I am developing an app where I use the call httpclient.getasync(url).
This is working in UWP. Infact this code was working in windows 8 also.But when I  tried today,It is giving weird exception(I didnot find anything in internet about this exception),Already spent lots of time.
Exception is Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher' to type 'System.Threading.IDispatcherQueue'
Here is my complete code.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        getMarketList();
    }

    public async Task<string> GetUserPlayList(string url) // Get currents users all public playlists
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            string url1 = url;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url1);
            var res = response.Content;
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<food> foodData = new ObservableCollection<food>();
    public async Task getMarketList()
    {
        string url = "I have a valid url";

        string format = await GetUserPlayList(url);

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiCallResponse>(format);

        foreach (var temp in data.result)
        {
            foodData.Add(temp);
        }
    }
```

Note-This was working earlier in windows 8 also and I am using preview builds of windows 10 and visual studio 2015

Comment: Try sending an `HttpRequestMessage _RequestMessage` with `_RequestMessage.HttpMethod.Get` and `_RequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(url);` using `HttpResponseMessage _response = await client.SendAsync(_RequestMessage)` to see if it remains in "context".

Comment: I forgot to mention that assigning a HttpClientHandler to your HttpClient() instance is a good thing to consider (if you haven't, of course).

Comment: @Jimi-Not working ,I tried that...added handler..it seems it is problem with preview builds

Comment: Allright, it was interesting to see the results. Post your findings if you come up with something. -- Since it looks like an async out of context event, have you tried with ConfigureAwait(false)? (It's just curiosity, I know - I can't test it).

Comment: @Jimi Yes I have tried as well..Do you know about this exception Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher' to type 'System.Threading.IDispatcherQueue

Comment: Nope. I remember I had some problems when DispatcherPriority became CoreDispatcherPriority in Win8.1. But it was about a configuration in an App.xaml. Doesn't seem related.

Comment: in your ctor try this: getMarketList().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
and don't forget to dispose of ur response message object.

Comment: I was right...As said earlier this is problem with windows versions..I updated my preview builds..Now its working..